# react-native-firebase Custom sound not working on android 8, android 9

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am working on a custom sound notification features. Custom sound is working properly on iOS and Android below version 8. Notifications also arrive in all versions of Android. But, the custom sound is not working on android 8 and 9. I have also created a channel Id.

Below I have shared my code. can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

```
  async checkPermission() {
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (enabled) {
        this.getToken();
      } else {
        this.requestPermission();
     }
    let channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
      "channelId",
      "Channel Name",
      firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
    ).setDescription("A natural description of the channel");
    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);


    firebase
      .notifications()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(notificationOpen => {
        if (notificationOpen) {
          const action = notificationOpen.action;
          const notification = notificationOpen.notification;
        }
      });

    // the listener returns a function you can use to unsubscribe
    this.unsubscribeFromNotificationListener = firebase
      .notifications()
      .onNotification(notification => {

        if (Platform.OS === "android") {
          const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
            "channelId",
            "Channel Name",
            firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
          )
            .setDescription("A natural description of the channel")
            .setSound(
              notification.data.sound ? notification.data.sound : "default"
            );

          firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

          const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
            sound: notification.data.sound
              ? notification.data.sound
              : "default",
            show_in_foreground: true
          })
            .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
            .setTitle(notification.title)
            .setSubtitle(notification.subtitle)
            .setBody(notification.body)
            .setData(notification.data)
            .setSound(
              notification.data.sound ? notification.data.sound : "default"
            )
            .android.setSmallIcon("notification_icon_black")
            .android.setChannelId("channelId") 
            .android.setAutoCancel(true)
            .android.setVibrate(1000)
            .android.setColor("#000000") // you can set a color here
            .android.setGroup(notification.notificationId)
            .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);

          firebase
            .notifications()
            .displayNotification(localNotification)
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
        } else if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
          const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
            .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
            .setTitle(notification.title)
            .setSound(
              notification.data.sound ? notification.data.sound : "default"
            )
            .setSubtitle(notification.subtitle)
            .setBody(notification.body)
            .setData(notification.data)
            .ios.setBadge(notification.ios.badge);

          firebase
            .notifications()
            .displayNotification(localNotification)
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
        }

      });

    const notificationOpen = await firebase
      .notifications()
      .getInitialNotification();
    if (notificationOpen) {
      const action = notificationOpen.action;
      const notification = notificationOpen.notification;
      if (notification.data) {
        //handle data
      }
    }

    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase
      .notifications()
      .onNotificationOpened(notificationOpen => {

        const notification = notificationOpen.notification;
        if (notification.data) {
          //handle data
        }
      });
  }



 async requestPermission() {
    try {
      await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
      // User has authorised
      this.getToken();
    } catch (error) {
      // User has rejected permissions
      console.log("permission rejected");
    }
  }

  async getToken() {
    let fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
    if (fcmToken) {
      console.log("fcm token===>", fcmToken);
    }
  }
```

Comment: RNcoremodule not found getting this problem. and not able to solve it. i also searched and tried many things. so how can i implement firebase notifications

Answer (score 2):

After spending the whole day, I have found the solution.
I have just cleared app data and restart my phone and it's working fine.

There is an issue because I have used custom sound on a particular type of notification.

I have also passed channel Id in the payload, to get a different sound based on the type of notification when the app is a background and kill mode.

```
{
    "to" : "DEVICE_TOKEN",

    "notification" : {
      "body"  : "NOTIFICATION BODY",
      "title" : "NOTIFICATION TITILE",
      "sound" : "default", //change your sound based on your requirement
      "android_channel_id":"CHANEEL_NAME", 
    }
  }
```

Comment: for me its working now .. i uninstalled app & closed metro bundle & restarted

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

First of all place your sound file in res/raw folder and also include setSound() in the notification channel ,

Second point, thanks to [@PatelDhara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7635085/patel-dhara) also make sure to remove your app from your device, so that new channel configuration will work properly.

Then put below line of code, it is working fine for me.

First create the channel.

```
const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(name, Description, firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.High)
.setDescription(ChannelName)
.setSound(default.mp3) //Set audio here
...
firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
```

Then:

```
const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
.setNotificationId(id)
.setTitle(title)
.setSound(channel.sound); //Get sound from channel and set in notification builder

notification
.android.setChannelId(channel.channelId)
firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
```

Also make sure that whenever you get payload, your audio file name located in your res/raw folder and sound value you are getting in payload should be same.

Like this:

```
{
    "to" : "DEVICE-TOKEN",

    "notification" : {
      "body"  : "NOTIFICATION BODY",
      "title" : "NOTIFICATION TITILE",
      "sound" : "default"
    }
  }
```

**Note : In react native there was problems with Android O in versions before 0.56.0(react native version), So try to upgrade your version.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried the above code but it's not working for android 8 and 9. My react-native version is  0.59.5. is there anything else which I have to manage in notification payload?

Comment: @PatelDhara : I've updated my working code, have a look at it

Comment: Hey, thanks for your support. But I have found a solution and I have just cleared app data and restart my phone and It's working...

Comment: RNcoremodule not found getting this problem. and not able to solve it. i also searched and tried many things. so how can i implement firebase notifications